# Migrating a question after it has been closed

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions

On [Crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com) we get a number of questions that end up closed that belong on other sites. I read on here that they will be migrated under certain circumstances. If those are not met, however, and the question receives 5 close votes from users, how do I then migrate the question to another site? In the past I have been reopening the question and then closing and migrating it. It seems like there should be a better way.

FWIW, [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12909/aes-implementation-not-working) is an example.